# How to read the multi nested JSON data in Spark

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

How read the multi nested JSON data in Spark. I have JSON file with
[image: Json Schema]

I need to extract this schema format to TherapeuticArea line item like as below:

```
trialTherapeuticAreas_ID,trialTherapeuticAreas_name,trialDiseases_id,trialDiseases_name,trialPatientSegments_id,trialPatientSegments_name
```

Comment: `df.select($"trialTherapeuticAreas")`;would be a good start

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**You need to `explode` the arrays in a nested manner and select the `struct` elements in separate columns** For that you would need `explode` inbuilt function and `select` api and *aliasing*.

**Code to try :**

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val finalDF = df.withColumn("trialTherapeuticAreas", explode(col("trialTherapeuticAreas")))
                                      .select(col("trialTherapeuticAreas.id").as("trialTherapeuticAreas_ID"), col("trialTherapeuticAreas.name").as("trialTherapeuticAreas_name"), explode(col("trialTherapeuticAreas.trialDiseases")).as("trialDiseases"))
                                      .select(col("trialTherapeuticAreas_ID"), col("trialTherapeuticAreas_name"), col("trialDiseases.id").as("trialDiseases_id"), col("trialDiseases.name").as("trialDiseases_name"), explode(col("trialDiseases.trialPatientSegments")).as("trialPatientSegments"))
                                      .select(col("trialTherapeuticAreas_ID"), col("trialTherapeuticAreas_name"), col("trialDiseases_id"), col("trialDiseases_name"), col("trialPatientSegments.id").as("trialPatientSegments_id"), col("trialPatientSegments.name").as("trialPatientSegments_name"))
```

You should get your requirements fulfilled

You can do the above *transformation* using three `withColumn` api and one `select` statement too.

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._
val finalDF = df.withColumn("trialTherapeuticAreas", explode(col("trialTherapeuticAreas")))
                .withColumn("trialDiseases", explode(col("trialTherapeuticAreas.trialDiseases")))
                .withColumn("trialPatientSegments", explode(col("trialDiseases.trialPatientSegments")))
                .select(col("trialTherapeuticAreas.id").as("trialTherapeuticAreas_ID"), col("trialTherapeuticAreas.name").as("trialTherapeuticAreas_name"), col("trialDiseases.id").as("trialDiseases_id"), col("trialDiseases.name").as("trialDiseases_name"), col("trialPatientSegments.id").as("trialPatientSegments_id"), col("trialPatientSegments.name").as("trialPatientSegments_name"))
```

**Consecutive use of `withColumn` is not recommended for huge dataset as it might give random output. The reason is that `withColumn` is distributed and order of execution is not proved to be followed in serial manner**